# Laravel Eloquent / keyBy doesn't work with related entity

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, orm, laravel-4, eloquent

**Code:**

```
public function getPosts(){
    $posts = Post::with('meta','taxonomies.terms.termMeta')
            ->where('post_type','service')
            ->orderBy('post_name')
            ->get()
            ->keyBy('ID')
            ->toArray();
   return $posts;
}
```

**Question :**

KeyBy() works when you want to change the entity(ex: Post) key but how to change the related entity key ex: I Want to key post related **meta** with **meta_key**.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Se5w.png)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to `transform()` each post and call the `keyBy()` method.

```
public function getPosts(){
    $posts = Post::with('meta','taxonomies.terms.termMeta')
            ->where('post_type','service')
            ->orderBy('post_name')
            ->get()
            ->transform(function ($post) {
                $meta = $post->meta;
                $post->meta = $meta->keyBy('meta_key');
                return $post;
            })
            ->keyBy('ID')
            ->toArray();
   return $posts;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code 1 : doesn't work ,I have noticed that you can alter the $post but not the related entities (ex:meta)   :

```
->transform(function ($post) {
            $meta = $post->meta;
            $post->meta = $meta->keyBy('meta_key');
            return $post;
        })
```

Code 2 : Works but it return only the meta array without the post information

```
 ->transform(function ($post) {
                $meta = $post->meta;
                $post->meta = $meta->keyBy('meta_key');
                return    $post->meta;
            })
```